# SAP Cloud Platform relation to SAPUI5?

Tags: sapui5, hana, sap-cloud-platform

I want to shed light on some of the ambiguous moments I encountered:

1. SAPUI5 is the name of the framework in JavaScript that can create Fiori apps.
2. SAP Cloud Platform acts like a server in the cloud for those apps.

So I can create an app that has no interaction with SAP HANA. Is that right?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SAPUI5 is a JavaScript web application framework. It is used by SAP to create SAP Fiori apps, and others can use it to create Fiori-like apps. However, it can also be used to create apps that do not follow the [Fiori Design Guidelines](https://experience.sap.com/fiori-design-web/), and are thus not Fiori-like apps. Furthermore, there is a free, open source version called OpenUI5.

[SAP Cloud Platform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAP_Cloud_Platform) is a platform-as-a-service that provides many different services, including a runtime for serving HTML apps like SAPUI5/OpenUI5 ("UI5") apps.

UI5 apps are often run from an SAP NetWeaver AS ABAP system (serving as an SAP Gateway system) or from SAP Cloud Platform, but as each of these apps is simply a collection of static files, they can be run from anywhere by including an index.html file.

So yes, you can create an app that has no interaction with SAP HANA.

Answer (score 2):

Technically, you can create an application with the SAPUI5 extensions that does not interact with an SAP instance, and execute this application in any compatible container.  However, if you read the fine print of most SAP licensing agreements related to this topic, you will notice a clause that indicates you could be charge for using the SAP version of the UI5 framework for non-SAP applications.

The OpenUI5 tools are OK, but without the aid of the SAP Web IDE, the use of this library is very code intensive.  Furthermore, while you can create and application with UI5 as a front end to a data server, you still have to have access to an compliant data source.

The other negatives are the lack of a formal, integrated authentication and authorization model for applications build using OpenUI5.  In the case of the SAPUI5 to build applications, you deploy to the SAP Fiori launchpad and benefit from an integrated authentication and authorization framework.

The following is an excerpt from the licensing agreement that you can view on the SAP Developer Tools page.
[SAP Developer Tools Page](https://tools.hana.ondemand.com)

Here is a link to the licensing agreement for convenience.
[Link to developer license](https://tools.hana.ondemand.com/developer-license-3_1.txt)

I have highlighted the sentences**strong text** that I understand to limit the use of the non-open source version of the SAPUI5 libraries to build non-SAP centric solutions.

T1.  LICENSE: SAP grants You a non-exclusive, non-transferable, non-sublicensable, revocable, limited use license to copy, reproduce and distribute the application programming interfaces ("API"), documentation, plug-ins, templates, scripts and sample code ("Tools") on a desktop, laptop, tablet, smart phone, or other appropriate computer device that You own or control (any, a "Computer") to create new applications ("Customer Applications"). **You agree that the Customer Applications will not:** (a) unreasonably impair, degrade or reduce the performance or security of any SAP software applications, services or related technology ("Software"); (b) enable the bypassing or circumventing of SAP's license restrictions and/or provide users with access to the Software to which such users are not licensed; (c) render or provide, without prior written consent from SAP, any information concerning SAP software license terms, Software, or any other information related to SAP products; or **(d) permit mass data extraction from an SAP product to a non-SAP product, including use, modification, saving or other processing of such data in the non-SAP product.** In exchange for the right to develop Customer Applications under this Agreement, You covenant not to assert any Intellectual Property Rights in Customer Applications created by You against any SAP product, service, or future SAP development.

Comment: The following is an excerpt from the licensing agreement that you can view on the SAP T